# is $(\mathbb{Q} \times (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}))\cup((\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\times\mathbb{Q})$ connected? path connected?

Tags: general-topology, irrational-numbers, connectedness

let $$X=(\mathbb{Q} \times (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}) ) \cup ((\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\times\mathbb{Q})
$$ and let $$\tau=\tau (\text{euclid})$$ 
what are the connected components of $$(X,\tau)$$ what are the path connected components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not path connected and the components are the points. There are no path between two points.

Take for example $A(1,\pi)$ and $B(\pi,1)$. Any path from $A$ to $B$ must cross the line $y=x$, which has no point in $X$.

For any other two points, simply make an appropiate translation.

Comment: +1. Yes, and the appropriate translation is $y = ax + b$ with $a,b$ rational.

Comment: what about the non path connected components?

Comment: The same analysis works for connected components. The line $y=x$ divides $X$ into two disjoint open sets on either side, and you can translate to divide any two arbitrary points into disjoint open sets.